# Increase string value

Tags: java, string

Java question here:
If i have a string "a", how can I "add" value to the string, so I get a "b" and so on?
like "a++"

Comment: What do you suppose you would get if you do `"ab"+1;`?

Comment: I think he wants a routine with returns the next letter in the alphabet

Comment: I get "ab1" .. I'm just talking about converting a string "a" to a "b", and a "b" to a "c". Just like when you do ++ on a int

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment a java String through all the possibilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342052/how-to-increment-a-java-string-through-all-the-possibilities)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String str = "abcde";
System.out.println(getIncrementedString(str));
```

**Output**

> bcdef

//this code will give next char in unicode sequence

```
public static String getIncrementedString(String str){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c:str.toCharArray()){
            sb.append(++c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the char primitive data type you can accomplish this:

```
char letter = 'a';
letter++;
System.out.println(letter);
```

prints out b

Answer (score 3):

i made some changes to te paulo eberman code, to handle digits and characters, if valuable for someone i share this mod....

```
public final static char MIN_DIGIT = '0';
public final static char MAX_DIGIT = '9';
public final static char MIN_LETTER = 'A';
public final static char MAX_LETTER = 'Z';

public String incrementedAlpha(String original) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(original);
    //int index = buf.length() -1;
    int i = buf.length() - 1;
    //while(index >= 0) {
    while (i >= 0) {
        char c = buf.charAt(i);
        c++;
        // revisar si es numero
        if ((c - 1) >= MIN_LETTER && (c - 1) <= MAX_LETTER) {
            if (c > MAX_LETTER) { // overflow, carry one
                buf.setCharAt(i, MIN_LETTER);
                i--;
                continue;
            }

        } else {
            if (c > MAX_DIGIT) { // overflow, carry one
                buf.setCharAt(i, MIN_DIGIT);
                i--;
                continue;
            }
        }
        // revisar si es numero
        buf.setCharAt(i, c);
        return buf.toString();
    }
    // overflow at the first "digit", need to add one more digit
    buf.insert(0, MIN_DIGIT);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

i hope be usefull for someone.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to increment char value by an integer

```
int a='a';
System.out.println("int: "+a);
a=a+3;
char c=(char)a;
System.out.println("char :"+c);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the string to a char.
- Increment the char.
- Convert the char
  back to a string.

Example:

```
    //convert a single letter string to char
    String a = "a";
    char tmp = a.charAt(0);

    //increment char
    tmp++;

    //convert char to string
    String b = String.valueOf(tmp);
    System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want something like `aaab` => `aaac` and not => `bbbc`, this would work:

```
public String incremented(String original) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(original);
    int index = buf.length() -1;
    while(index >= 0) {
       char c = buf.charAt(i);
       c++;
       buf.setCharAt(i, c);
       if(c == 0) { // overflow, carry one
          i--;
          continue;
       }
       return buf.toString();
    }
    // overflow at the first "digit", need to add one more digit
    buf.insert(0, '\1');
    return buf.toString();
}
```

This treats all characters (in fact `char` values) the same, and fails (does strange stuff) for some unicode code-points outside the first plane (which occupy two char values in a String).

If you only want to use *english lowercase letters* as digits, you can try this variant:

```
public final static char MIN_DIGIT = 'a';
public final static char MAX_DIGIT = 'z';

public String incrementedAlpha(String original) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(original);
    int index = buf.length() -1;
    while(index >= 0) {
       char c = buf.charAt(i);
       c++;
       if(c > MAX_DIGIT) { // overflow, carry one
          buf.setCharAt(i, MIN_DIGIT);
          i--;
          continue;
       }
       buf.setCharAt(i, c);
       return buf.toString();
    }
    // overflow at the first "digit", need to add one more digit
    buf.insert(0, MIN_DIGIT);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

This does `a` => `b` => `c`, `y` => `z` => `aa` => `ab`.

if you want to do more calculation with the string, consider staying with StringBuilder (or StringBuffer for multithreaded access) instead of repeatedly copying between String and StringBuilder.
Or use a class made to do this, like BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured everything out :) I'm working from front of string, to end. Done my own method. Works like a charm :)

Comment: okay, so you are using little-endian, compared to my big-endian. Could you post your variant in an own answer?