# Find all combinations 6 numbers using only 0,1 and 2

Tags: r, combinations

Is there a simple way of finding all the combinations of 6 digits using only 0, 1 and 2?

So it starts like `000000` and finishes `222222`

I have looked online but all i can find is the formula for finding how many there are but i need a list of all of them

If there is a code in R that will be even better

It is not completely neccessary but if there is a way to create a list where the `1st and 4th digit sum to a maximum of 2`, `2nd and 5th digit sum to a maximum of 2` and `3rd and 6th digit sum to a maximum of 2`

Thankyou

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342052/how-to-increment-a-java-string-through-all-the-possibilities

Comment: thankyou, but i can't use java...i have adjusted my question to something i am able to use :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 6)))
```

Adding a `rev` in there gives a different order that might feel more natural:

```
do.call(paste0, rev(expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 6))))
```

I will only give you a hint for your new (added) question as I am now worried I might be doing your homework. `expand.grid` returns a data.frame. With a little work on it, you can probably extract the `subset` of rows that only matter to you.

Comment: haha its not homework, its part of my job and im not that great with r yet. but thankyou anyway :)